# Remove "estimated for {country}" text after tax amount in Woocommerce checkout page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, tax

I set up a 19% standard tax amount in my Woocommerce Online-Shop. Unfortunatley - now there is a text "estimated for Germany" behind the (includes 20,12 €... part below the total-amount in my checkout page (see image below). I guess it displays the text because the calculated tax amount has a lot of decimals.

[image]

HTML

```
<small class="includes_tax">
(includes 
    <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">20.12
        <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€<span>
    </span> estimated for Germany)
</small>
```

This is not the case by using a 20% tax amount.

**How to remove the "estimated for Germany" text?**

I was not able find any filter or html class to target the text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The responsable code is [**in there**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_cart_totals_order_total_html.html#293-324), located in `wc_cart_totals_order_total_html()` function.

So we can use hooked function hooked in `woocommerce_cart_totals_order_total_html` filter hook, where we'll remove this annoying behavior (added compatibility for versions since 2.6.x and up):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_totals_order_total_html', 'custom_cart_totals_order_total_html', 20, 1 );
function custom_cart_totals_order_total_html( $value ){
    $value = '<strong>' . WC()->cart->get_total() . '</strong> ';

    // If prices are tax inclusive, show taxes here.
    $incl_tax_display_cart = version_compare( WC_VERSION, '3.3', '<' ) ? WC()->cart->tax_display_cart == 'incl'  : WC()->cart->display_prices_including_tax();
    if ( wc_tax_enabled() && $incl_tax_display_cart ) {
        $tax_string_array = array();
        $cart_tax_totals  = WC()->cart->get_tax_totals();

        if ( get_option( 'woocommerce_tax_total_display' ) == 'itemized' ) {
            foreach ( $cart_tax_totals as $code => $tax ) {
                $tax_string_array[] = sprintf( '%s %s', $tax->formatted_amount, $tax->label );
            }
        } elseif ( ! empty( $cart_tax_totals ) ) {
            $tax_string_array[] = sprintf( '%s %s', wc_price( WC()->cart->get_taxes_total( true, true ) ), WC()->countries->tax_or_vat() );
        }

        if ( ! empty( $tax_string_array ) ) {
            $taxable_address = WC()->customer->get_taxable_address();
            $estimated_text  = '';
            $value .= '<small class="includes_tax">' . sprintf( __( '(includes %s)', 'woocommerce' ), implode( ', ', $tax_string_array ) . $estimated_text ) . '</small>';
        }
    }
    return $value;
}
```

This code goes on function.php file of your active child theme (or theme).

Tested and works.

Answer (score 1):

To simply remove that text from cart total I used:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_totals_order_total_html', function ($html) {
    return substr($html, 0, strpos($html, '<small class="includes_tax">'));
}, 10, 2 );
```